# Increasing each subplot's size and adjusting their width, matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I have a dataset from sci-kit learn, fetch_lfw_people.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# plotting faces
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,5)
# fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=2)

for enumerate_counter, axi in enumerate(ax.flat):
    axi.imshow(faces.images[enumerate_counter], cmap='bone')
    axi.set(xticks=[], yticks=[],xlabel=faces.target_names[faces.target[enumerate_counter]])
```

while trying to show images using subplots and labeling each image with proper name, I want to increase the size of each images and also separate them wide enough so that names do not overlap.

I've tried

```
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=2)
```

however this separates images so that names do not overlap however images gets smaller in size.

Anyway I could resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I will give some examples with some sample numbres that may lead you in the right direction:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
```

OR

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
```

Comment: thanks! haha fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,5,figsize=(20,10)) did this and works!

Comment: Cool great to hear this helps.